# Three.js with WebBrowser control?

Tags: three.js, webbrowser-control

Under Visual Studio 2017, in a winform application, I try to use a webbrowser to navigate to a page using Three.js.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessageBox.Show(mockupBrowser.Version.ToString(), "WebBrowser version");

        mockupBrowser.Navigate("https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html");

    }
```

But during the loadding of Three.js, I have a JavaScript error (line 6852 car 3)

My WebBrowser control version is 11.0.16299.125 and I am under windows 10.

I have no problem when I use directly Google Chrome or Internet Explorer.

Any solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424283/webgl-ie-in-webbrowser-control) answer.

WebBrowser Control is just a wrapper over IE, and depending on the configuration of the machine it may wrap IE7, which does not support WebGL at all.

Comment: Yes !  I have used a script to display the MSIE version and it is 7.0
I will modify my emulation key to have MSIE 11
Thanks !

Comment: No problem. Please remember to mark the answer as accepted so others can find it more easily.

Comment: I have find the way to change the webrowser emulation version to "IE 11"
It works well with my local script calling my local Three.js but it doesn't work with a URL example... 
My objective is to work locally so it is OK !
Thank you :-)